# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.AudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, voip, voip-android

I am getting weird type of Crash in the application, captured during Crash Analytics, even I didn't use the code for Bluetooth devices and didn't used these lines **isBluetoothA2dpOn()** as well. Furthermore, I couldn't trace the code that from where it has been triggered by the trace logs captured by **Crash Analytics**. If someone have faced the same issue, than suggest the best answer for that.

> **at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10779)**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.AudioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()' on a null object reference
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.sendAccessibilityEventForUnicodeCharacter(KeyboardView.java:998)
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.showPreview(KeyboardView.java:883)
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1301)
       at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1223)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10779)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2864)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2491)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:609)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1890)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3240)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(Unknown Source:68)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(Unknown Source:68)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:571)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:11008)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5155)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5007)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4684)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4741)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4551)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4559)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4532)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6985)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

**Edited dispatchTouchEvent**

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (touchListener != null) {
                    if (!haltRegistration) {
                        touchListener.onTouchEvent();
                    } else {
                        haltRegistration = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "listener was null...");
                }
            }
        }, 300);

    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: share your `dispatchTouchEvent` code

Comment: @Anmol please check the code. The listener is properly initialise and the conditions is accurate. But the issue I am facing is different from the code we have done.

Comment: can you tell at which line u are getting this error in dispatchTouch?

Comment: @Anmol if you check the description of my problem you will get what I have written. "I couldn't trace the code that from where it has been triggered ".

Comment: ok, can't help you with this much info.  (Y)

Comment: @Anmol thanks for your time.

Comment: what are you doing in `touchListener.onTouchEvent();`?

Comment: @jim that is just a custom function listen by dispatchTouchEvent, but the issue I have posted is something different from this code.